# Sometimes Handlebars does not load object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create divs using an object I pass with res.render(). However, sometimes the divs are created and sometimes they are not (if I refresh the page). I also use Bootstrap.

js/express:

```
router.get('/', checkSignIn, function(req, res, next) {
    db = new sqlite3.Database(file);
    var tasks = {};
    db.serialize(function () {
        var query = "SELECT tasks.id, tasks.name, tasks.status FROM tasks JOIN users ON users.privilege = tasks.privilege WHERE users.id = '" + req.session.userid + "'";
        db.all(query, function (err, rows) {
            for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                tasks[i] = {
                    name: rows[i].name,
                    status: rows[i].status
                };
                console.log(tasks[i]);
            }
        });
    });
    db.close();
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Home',
        css: ['style.css', 'dist/wu-icons-style.css'],
        username: req.session.username,
        tasks: tasks
    });
});
```

hbs:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel-group">
                    {{#each tasks}}
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">{{name}}</h3></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">{{status}}</div>
                    </div>
                    {{/each}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The `tasks` object is properly populated every time, according to the `console.log()` that I've added. So I think the problem lies in Handlebars.

I kind of found a solution here: [Handlebars not print {{this}} in each helper](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/832), but I don't use `this`. I tried `./name` and `./status`, but it didn't help. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is async javascript, not handlebars. Your `tasks` object is populating, but you're rendering the html prior to that. If you `console.log(tasks)` right after the current position of `db.close()`, it will be an empty object. You need to move the render function inside the database call:

```
router.get('/', checkSignIn, function(req, res, next) {
    db = new sqlite3.Database(file);
    db.serialize(function () {
        var query = "SELECT tasks.id, tasks.name, tasks.status FROM tasks JOIN users ON users.privilege = tasks.privilege WHERE users.id = '" + req.session.userid + "'";
        db.all(query, function (err, rows) {
            var tasks = {};
            for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                tasks[i] = {
                    name: rows[i].name,
                    status: rows[i].status
                };
                console.log(tasks[i]);
            }
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Home',
                css: ['style.css', 'dist/wu-icons-style.css'],
                username: req.session.username,
                tasks: tasks
            });
        });
    });
    db.close();
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thanks for your answer. It worked. However, moving `db.close()` inside `db.all()` gives an error. So I only moved `res.render()` inside the `db.all()` function and that worked. So it didn't work because it started rendering before the previous function was finished, right?